# Getting thumbnails from photos library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to save the thumbnails from the iphone photo library, and i want to use them in my application, but not by selecting them, i want it to work automatically. so i run the app, and the thumbnails will appear in the middle of the screen in a scrollable tableview. (5 thumbs in each "page").
Like this: http://cl.ly/0z2m261J2I0B461n2L25

what is the best way to do it? Oh , and of course if a user touch a thumnail the large image will appear in a different view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an `ALAssetsLibrary` instance.
2. Send a `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` message to your assets library object.
3. In the block, you are passed an `ALAssetsGroup` instance over which you again iterate with `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:`.
4. In that block, you get an `ALAsset` that you can then ask for its `thumbnail` (a `CGImageRef`) or its `representation` (an instance of `ALAssetRepresentation`), which in turn you can get an image to display from.

Comment: By the way, if anyone needs help about it, here is a nice tutorial video about ALAssetsLibrary: http://vimeo.com/13187660